# Reference to equivariant Gromov-Hausdorff convergence

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

I am looking for a reference to the following notions and facts below which, I think, I can prove, but which might be known to experts.

Let us fix a finite group $G$. Consider the class of all compact metric spaces equipped with an action of $G$ by isometries.  The elements of it are triples $(X,d,a)$ where $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space, $a$ is an  action.
**Definition.** The $G$-equivarint GH-distance between two such triples is $$d^G_{GH}((X,d,a),(Y,h,b)):= inf_{D} D_H(X,Y),$$
where the inf is taken over all $G$-invariant metrics $D$ on the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$ extending the original metrics $d$ and $h$ on them; $D_H$ denotes the Hausdorff distance.

**Proposition.**
(1) $d^G_{GH}$ satisfies the triangle inequality.

(2) $ d^G_{GH}((X,d,a),(Y,h,b))=0$ if and only if there exists a $G$-equivariant isometry between $X$ and $Y$.

Let us denote by $\mathcal{X}^G$ the set of isomorphism classes of such triples. Thus it is the metric space with the induced metric.

Let $\mathcal{X}$ denote the usual space of isometry classes of compact metric spaces equipped with the usual (non-equivariant) Gromov-Hausdorff metric.

**Proposition.**
The canonical map (forgetting the action)
$$\mathcal{X}^G\to \mathcal{X}$$
is proper.

Comment: Given $(X,d,a)$ and $(Y,h,b)$, suppose I extend $d$ and $h$ to the disjoint union by choosing $p\in X$, $q\in Y$, $\epsilon>0$, and defining the distance from $x\in X$ to $y\in Y$ as $\inf(d(a_g x,p)+\epsilon+h(q, b_g y):g\in G)$. Is that a legitimate $G$-equivariant metric? If so it would give a distance of $\epsilon$ between $X$ and $Y$, and the infimum in the question would always be zero.

Comment: @MattF.: I think it is not a legitimate metric.  In fact when the group $G$ is trivial one recovers the standard (non-equivariant) Gromov-Hausdorff distance which does not always vanish.

Comment: After checking, I think it is a legitimate metric, but it gives a distance of something like $\epsilon + \sup(\min(d(p,x), h(q,y)))$, so it does not make the definition trivial.

Comment: I'm pretty late to this! But I think you want Lemma 3.4 from my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0531, which puts the equivariant Gromov-Hausdorff distance into that disjoint union context.

Comment: @JohnHarvey: Thank you! I already published my paper where I needed that :(( But your paper looks interesting in any case.